# Getting RcppArmadillo working in Rstudio using .cpp file

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm a newbie with this, so sorry for the basic question.  I have managed to get Rcpp working but need a function in Armadillo, and I am just not getting it right.  I know the code is bad, like I said I am a newbie in C++, but I would be very grateful if someone could help me get this example going.  My code from the .cpp file in Rstudio is as follows.  I am running latest R, and Rstudio.  Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

/*** R
require(Rcpp)
require(RcppArmadillo)
#Population of size N
N = 350
#Set size
m = 3
#Number of cycles
C = 20
#Final number of analysed units
n = C * m
#make the r vector of ranks
r <- rep(1:m, length.out = n)

#initialise alpha matrix nxn
alpha <- matrix(0, ncol = N, nrow = n)
  */

// [[Rcpp::export]]
unsigned nChoosek( unsigned n, unsigned k )
{
  if (k > n) return 0;
  if (k * 2 > n) k = n-k;
  if (k == 0) return 1;

  int result = n;
  for( int i = 2; i <= k; ++i ) {
    result *= (n-i+1);
    result /= i;
  }
  return result;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix alphaC(NumericVector r, int N, int m, int n, int C, 
NumericMatrix alpha){
  int S = r.size();
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  double c = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){

    for (int j = 0; j < S; ++j){

      a = nChoosek(i, (r[j] - 1));
      b = nChoosek((N - (i + 1)),( m - r[j]));
      c = nChoosek(N, m);

      alpha(j,i) = a*b/c;  

      //std::cout << "a*b/c: " << a*b/c << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return(alpha);
}

/*** R
#Create first order probabilities
pi <- 1 - apply((1 - alphaC(r,N,m,n,C,alpha)), 2, prod)
  plot(pi)
  */

/*** R
#Second order inclusion properties.
pii <- matrix(0, ncol = N, nrow = N)
  */

// [[Rcpp::export]]

int times(NumericVector vec){
  int sum = 1;
  sum = arma::prod(vec);
  return sum;
}

/*** R
vec = 1:5
times(vec)
*/
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I guess you have to convert `NumericVector` to `arma::vec` by inserting a line   like `arma::vec v = as<arma::vec>(vec);` and then use `sum = arma::prod(v);`. I am a beginner of cpp and not sure whether this is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code contains **many** things that are not relevant here. Please try to provide a **minimal** example next time, together with the error message you got. Anyway, you will need an Armadillo data structure to work with `arma::prod`. You can either create this directly as shown by @mt1022 in the comments, or have it done implicitly by defining a function with suitable arguments:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double times(arma::vec vec){
  double result = arma::prod(vec);
  return result;
}

/*** R
vec <- 1:5 + 0.5
times(vec)
*/
```

Note that I have changed the return type to double, since the product of a `numeric` vector is in general not representable as a `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help with these question, Ralf.  It's appreciated.  And upvoted :)

Comment: Thank you.  I thought that was a minimal example.  The upper portion was code that was working correctly, and the small piece at the bottom was my minimal example.  To be fair if I could get a minimum working example going I would not have needed to ask the question.  Thank you for your help.  I had no one else to ask.

Comment: @user259933 You are welcome. Please have a look at [mcve] to understand what is meant by minimal example. It does not have to be working code — as you said you won’t have to ask the question then — but it should be the minimum amount of code that reproduces the error. In your case only the few lines at the bottom. Throw in the error message and you are all set.